# javascript code not proceeding after await

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use [cookie-toss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-toss) library on my NuxtJS to try and share authentication with tokens between different domains. The problem is when I try their example to get the localstorage in sattelite2.com.. The code does not proceed in `console.log(result)` as shown below

```
  async mounted() {
    console.log("went in");
    const result = await get({
      iframeUrl: "http://satellite2.com:3000/ckjtt/",
      dataKey: "chocolate-chip-oatmeal"
    });
    // const result = localStorage['ckj-user']
    console.dir(`result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
  },
```

I am a part time frontend developer who has relied on frameworks, so the basic of async/await is something that I have not fully understand. I can not understand why it does not proceed based on his repo

Comment: short answer: you need to `await` that `get()` call

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your `await get(...)` call in an async `IIFE` or a plain `async` function. The `await` keyword can be only used in an `async` function. `Top level await` will be introduced in the future:
[https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await#:~:text=Top%2Dlevel%20await%20enables%20developers,they%20start%20evaluating%20their%20body](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await#:%7E:text=Top%2Dlevel%20await%20enables%20developers,they%20start%20evaluating%20their%20body).

It is also a good practice to introduce error handling in your code. With await `try - catch` is a common practice.

```js
import { get } from "cookie-toss";

async function fetchData() {
  let result;
  try {
    result = await get({
      iframeUrl: 'https://hub.com/cookie-toss.html',
      dataKey: 'chocolate-chip-oatmeal',
    });
    console.log(result);
  } catch(error) {
      console.error(`Unable to fetch data. Error: ${error.message || 'Unexpected error'}`);
      // error handling
   }
}

fetchData();
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I updated my question.. I actually used `async mounted`

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada so you're using vuejs. Please include that in the tags next time.

Comment: Not familiar with `Vue` but `js` syntax is the same. Now you should include `await` before `get<Promise>`. Basically `await` tries to resolve your `promise` and I bet that `get` returns a `Promise`.

Comment: Oh, I mentioned `NuxtJS` but ok, I will try your solution

Comment: But have you tried this `cookie-toss` in your actual localhost?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada check my answer

Answer (score 0):

`mounted` is already predefined as a regular function. so adding `async` wont do anything. you have to declare your method first before calling in your `created` or `mounted`

```
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                results: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getDataFromApi()
        },
        methods: {
            async getDataFromApi() {
                this.results = await get({
                  iframeUrl: "http://satellite2.com:3000/ckjtt/",
                  dataKey: "chocolate-chip-oatmeal"
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

since you're using nuxtJS you can just use the `async fetch` already provided

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        results: null
      }
    },
    activated() {
      // Call fetch again if last fetch more than 30 sec ago
      if (this.$fetchState.timestamp <= Date.now() - 30000) {
        this.$fetch()
      }
    },
    async fetch() {
      this.results= await get({
              iframeUrl: "http://satellite2.com:3000/ckjtt/",
              dataKey: "chocolate-chip-oatmeal"
      })
    }
  }
```

or `asyncData` (I would recommend this)

```
import { get } from "cookie-toss";

export default {
    async asyncData({ params, $http }) {
      const results = await get({
              iframeUrl: "http://satellite2.com:3000/ckjtt/",
              dataKey: "chocolate-chip-oatmeal"
      })
      return { results}
    }
  }
```

then you can access it in your component with `this.results` or `results` on your template.

you can read more about it here https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/

additionally you can create a plugin to for your `get` from `cookie-toss`

create a file called `cookie-toss.js` in your plugins folder and add this code to it

```
import { get } from 'cookie-toss';

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
    inject('get', get);
}
```

and then in your plugins array in your `nuxt.config.js` add the path to your plugin

```
 plugins: [
    '@/plugins/cookie-toss.js'
  ],
```

now you can access your get in the app context.

```
export default {
  async asyncData({app, $get}) {
    // app.$get or $get
    const result = await $get({
      iframeUrl: "http://satellite2.com:3000/ckjtt/",
      dataKey: "chocolate-chip-oatmeal",
    });
    return { result };
  },
};
```

if you get the error of `window is not defined` add `mode: 'spa'` to your `nuxt.config.js` or `ssr: false`

Comment: Did you try this in your local? I get this error: `window is not defined` in the first place

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada you can create a plugin so you can have access to the `get` in your `asyncData method`

Comment: I think you want to take a look at this? https://github.com/JohnMealy23/cookie-toss

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada Already did. You can create a plugin and expose it to app context as `$get` in which case you use it in your `asyncData`

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada yup i already made the plugin. but in your `nuxt.config.js` you can add `mode: "spa"` or `ssr: false` to remove the `window is not defined ` error. I'll edit my answer to include the plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same for me, it is still not executing console after `await $get`.. Can you provide me a working project in github? I will give you a big bountry  if you do so

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada that's cos `http://satellite2.com:3000/ckjtt/` is not an available resource. check your console.for the error.

Comment: I used an existing resource. You can try all of this in just one localhost